# How to get the x-axis to intercept the y-axis at zero in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple line graph, that contains points less than zero on the y-axis. The x-axis is at the bottom of the graph, and thus does not intercept the y-axis at y = 0.

How can I get the x=axis to intercept at y=0 in ggplot2?

**Example code:**

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = seq(-30, 65, by = 5))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue")
p
```

[image: Line graph]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't understand exactly, do you want the labels along the line y=0?

Comment: Yes - sorry if this isn't clear in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Limit the y-axis display with `coord_cartesian`

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(-5, 15),
                 y=c(-25, 25))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,50))
```

[image]

Option 2: Shift the xaxis label manually.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust = 120))
```

[image]

Comment: Option 1 isn't feasible as it cuts off half of the graph.
Option 2 is exactly what I was looking for. I'm new to r and didn't know about the vjust function. Thanks very much!